# read_stream does not give from user picture

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

i am getting feeds from facebook with public_profile,email,read_stream permissions in javascript and the object which return has a from object in which id and name of from user returns but i need picture also can anyone help plz?
Thanks in advance.

```
FB.api("/me/feed",function (response) {
    if (response && !response.error) {
        var feed = response.data[0];
        console.log(feed.from);
    }
});
```

output like:

```
from: Object
id: "100000810224706" 
name: "Raja Imran"
```

Comment: show all the code please.

Comment: thats solved now its only returning 25 records i also tried to put limit like /feed?limit=50, my problem is i need more than 25 records, how can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get other records by pagination and your next and previous links are exist in your response object which are accesible by `console.log(response.paging);`

Comment: ahhh, great, sorry its my stupidity that i have not checked that, sorry again, Thanks again. u r great.

Answer (score 0):

Profil pictures are always build like this
https://graph.facebook.com/[userid]/picture

for your case this would be
https://graph.facebook.com/100000810224706/picture

another alternative would be to make a nested request were you also request the picture from graph api

something like this:
https;//graph.facebook.com/me/feed?fields=id,message,from{id,name,picture}

Comment: Thanks buddy its working with this /feed?fields=id,message,from{id,name,picture}

Comment: but its only returning 25 records i also tried to put limit my problem is i need more than 25 records, how can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can request picture field explicitly in query string like /feed?fields=from{id,picture} etc.

Comment: Thanks buddy its working with this /feed?fields=id,message,from{id,name,picture}